# Group the values in the dictionary based on the substring in the value from list of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary like below

```
[
{'id': 'AA111', 'id_alias': '111', 'name': 'PP_LL_G_1111_aaaaaa'},
{'id': 'AA222', 'id_alias': '222', 'name': 'PP_LL_G_2222_aaaaaa'},
{'id': 'AA111', 'id_alias': '111', 'name': 'PP_LL_L_1111_aaaaaa'},
{'id': 'AA222', 'id_alias': '222', 'name': 'PP_LL_U_2222_aaaaaa'},
{'id': 'AA111', 'id_alias': '111', 'name': 'PP_LL_U_1111_aaaaaa'},
{'id': 'AA333', 'id_alias': '333', 'name': 'PP_LL_L_3333_aaaaaa'},
]
```

i want to get the names based on the id in the below format from the above input

`names` which contains either `'G', 'U' or 'L'` should be replaced and grouped together with `'GUL'` based on the `id`.

From the above input id `'AA111'` have below names

```
 PP_LL_G_1111_aaaaaa  // contains G here
 PP_LL_L_1111_aaaaaa  // contains L here
 PP_LL_U_1111_aaaaaa  // contains U here
```

It contains both `G, L and U`. So end result should be like below.

```
PP_LL_GUL_1111_aaaaaa  // G,U and L grouped into one

start with underscore (_) 

'G' should comes in first place 
'U' should comes in second place 
'L' should be in the third place 

end with undersocore (_)
```

So the end result will be like below

```
[
{'id': 'AA111', 'id_alias': '111', 'name': 'PP_LL_GUL_1111_aaaaaa'}, // _GUL_
{'id': 'AA222', 'id_alias': '222', 'name': 'PP_LL_GU_2222_aaaaaa'},  // _GU_
{'id': 'AA333', 'id_alias': '333', 'name': 'PP_LL_L_3333_aaaaaa'},   // _L_
]
```

i was trying to achieve the same using multiple for loops and if condition like below, which i feel not a best case to solve the issue

Also this one not solved my issue.

```
temp = {}
for a in result_dict:
    if a['id'] in temp:
        temp[a['id']].append(a['name'])
    else:
        temp.update({a['id']: [a['name']]})

            
# combine G, U and L into one
for id, name_list in temp.items():
    p_name = name_list[0]
    for s in name_list:
        if '_G_' in s:
            p_name.replace('_G_', '_G')
        if '_U_' in s:
            p_name.replace('_U_', 'U')
        if '_L_' in s:
            physicp_nameal_name.replace('_L_', 'L')
```